# farmed deployment on Tomcat doesn't work correctly

Tags: tomcat

I'm trying to set farmed WAR deployment between two Tomcat servers, which are united in cluster. I think the WAR file hasn't been copied yet, but deployment already starts - Tomcat throws following exception:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid CEN header (bad signature)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
...
```

Could you tell me how to avoid this problem?

Comment: Please check you deployed files. Are they corrupted? You deploy via Tomcat Manager?